# '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, text, nlp, readability, flesch-kincaid

I'm trying to look at the readability scores for a text file using this Python code:

`posts = open("/Users/jchavis/Desktop/Data/posts.txt","r")`

`readability_scores = Textatistic(posts).scores`

`flesch = readability_scores['flesch_score']`

`print('The Flesch Reading Ease is %.2f' % (flesch))`

However, I receive this error:

**AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'**

I'm not sure what needs to be corrected. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Presumably, `Textastics` expects a string, not a file-like object from which a string can be read. Maybe `Textastics(posts.read()).scores`? (I'm basing this on the fact that `replace` is a `str` method.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your reply. I get the following error when I try that approach: 
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte"

Comment: Then the file you are opening isn't UTF-8-encoded; provide the correct encoding with `open`'s `encoding` argument.